# Difference between – and - signs for subtraction operation

Tags: c

I could not understand the difference between these two operators.

The usage gives difference in output.

following snippet gives error:

```
void main()
{
    float x = 1.1 ;
    while ( x == 1.1 )
    {
        printf ( "\n%f", x ) ;
        x = x  – 0.1 ;
    }
}
```

but the following works ok:

```
void main()
{
    float x = 1.1 ;
    while ( x == 1.1 )
    {
        printf ( "\n%f", x ) ;
        x = x - 0.1 ;
    }
}
```

Please let me know the difference.

Comment: `gives error`...what error?

Comment: One looks like the normal `-` ASCII character, the other looks like some Unicode character, which the compiler probably can't handle.

Comment: BTW, `void main()` --> `int main(void).`

Comment: How do you produce these characters? What key (combinations) on your keyboard?

Comment: That's an EN DASH (U+2013); it's not an operator. The question would have been so much more interesting if you had used a − MINUS SIGN (U+2212) which is a mathematical operator, at least according to Unicode!

Comment: @MrLister yep, added the same into my answer. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler expects a `-` character for subtraction. This has ASCII code 45(decimal) == 0x2D(hex)

It is present on every keyboard, usually two times (normal keyboard, Keypad)

These days we have Unicode and there are many "characters" which look similar but have a different *meaning* and the compiler will not recognize these "exotic" charactes as the normal minus operator but produce a "syntax error" instead.

Answer (score 4):

> *I could not understand the difference between these two operators*

The minus sign `-` is a vaild *operator* in `c`, the binary subtraction operator, decimal `45` in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

The other one , called (any of `en`/`em`/`figure`/`quotation`) **[dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)** is not a valid `c` *operator*, (it is Unicode character). Compiler is very right to complain.

FWIW, in your code,

```
 while ( x == 1.1 )
```

will *almost* always yield *FALSE* as it *does not do what you expect it to do*. [That is not how you compare floating point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). You should change your logic.

Also, please note that the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference - one character is a minus character, the other is some obscure character that looks like a minus